# How to get the sample rate of a microphone/input device using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audiocontext, sample-rate

When you create a new `AudioContext` it sets the sample rate to the default *output* device. This is expected default behavior. Does anyone know if there is there any way to get the sample rate of the input device in Javascript?

We can see in the docs for [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/AudioContext) it says this about `sampleRate`

> The value will typically be between 8,000 Hz and 96,000 Hz; the default
> will vary depending on the output device, but the sample rate 44,100
> Hz is the most common. **If the sampleRate property is not included in
> the options, or the options are not specified when creating the audio
> context, the new context's output device's preferred sample rate is
> used by default.**

Example of how I'm using it:

```js
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false});
const context = new AudioContext();
context.sampleRate // This is the default output device's sample rate. I need the default input sampleRate
```

I've been scouring the docs and the internet for a way to do this but have not found anything useful. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the `sampleRate` of the audio track within the stream like this:

```
const sampleRate = stream.getAudioTracks()[0].getSettings().sampleRate;
```

You can then use that to create the `AudioContext`.

```
const context = new AudioContext({ sampleRate });
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you so much. I was looking on the audio tracks but I guess I missed this `getSettings` method